# How do I properly include a wx.grid inside a wx.GridBagSizer?

Tags: wxpython, wxwidgets

I'm just beginning to lean python and the use of wxpython widgets. I tried creating a 50 X 3 wx.grid.  If it's the only object in a panel, then there's no problem.  However, if I tried to include other objects by using a GridBagSizer then it seem to occupy only one cell of the sizer even of I specified span=(5,3) for 5 row, 3 columns.

I tried using a separate BoxSizer for the panel containing the grid (commented in my code) by it also didn't work.

```
import wx
import wx.grid

class Screen(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(parent, title=title,
            size=(500, 500))
                self.paneltab = wx.Panel(self.panel)
        self.paneltab.SetSize(size=(150,150))

        #this is the grid I want to display properly
        self.tab = wx.grid.Grid(self.paneltab)

        self.tab.CreateGrid(50,3)
        self.tab.SetColSize(0,150)
        self.tab.SetColSize(1,100)
        self.tab.SetColSize(2,50)
        self.tab.SetColLabelValue(0, "USER")
        self.tab.SetColLabelValue(1, "Log-In Time")
        self.tab.SetColLabelValue(2, "Status")
        self.SetLayout()
        self.Centre()

    def SetLayout(self):
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(0,0)
        #sizertab = wx.BoxSizer(wx.VERTICAL)
        #self.paneltab.SetSizer(sizerTab)


        sizer.Add((100,-1),     pos=(0,0))
        sizer.Add((100,-1),     pos=(0,1))
        sizer.Add((100,-1),     pos=(0,2))
        text1 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label='Hello', style = 
            wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        text2 = wx.StaticText(self.panel, label='World', style = 
            wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        sizer.Add(text1,   pos=(1,0),  span=(1,1), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND,  
            border=5)
        sizer.Add(text2,   pos=(1,2),  span=(1,2), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND,  
            border=5)

        #sizer.Add(sizertab,     pos=(2,1),  span=(5,2), 
            flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND,  border=5)
        sizer.Add(self.paneltab,     pos=(2,0),  span=(5,3), 
            flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND,  border=5)

        self.panel.SetSizer(sizer)
        sizer.Fit(self)
        self.panel.SetBackgroundColour("thristle1")

def main():
    app = wx.App()                            
    screen = Screen(None, title='Server Consule')
    screen.Show()  
    app.MainLoop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

I expected the grid to be displayed in a span=(5,3) but it seem to be displayed in a span=(1,1).

Comment: Some might question the reasoning behind attempting to shoehorn a 50x3 grid into a tiny little slot in a gridbagsizer!

Answer (score 0):

I think you miss this in your code:

```
    self.panel = wx.Panel(self)
```

And to make, your StaticText for example, "use" the whole space maybe try it like this:

```
    sizer.Add(text1,(1,0),(1,1),1,wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND,5)
    sizer.Add(text2,(1,2),(1,2),1,wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND,5)
```

Important is the "1" before the flags. That makes them use the whole space.

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean that you want something like this:
[image]

As I said in my comment, it's going to look a bit odd. You might be better off just using multiple `BoxSizer`'s.
Your code amended to produce the above is:

```
import wx
import wx.grid

class Screen(wx.Frame):
    def __init__(self, parent, title):
        super(Screen, self).__init__(parent, title=title, size=(500, 500))

        self.paneltab = wx.Panel(self)
        self.paneltab.SetSize((500,250))
        #this is the grid I want to display properly
        self.tab = wx.grid.Grid(self.paneltab)
        self.tab.CreateGrid(50,3)
        self.tab.SetColSize(0,150)
        self.tab.SetColSize(1,100)
        self.tab.SetColSize(2,50)
        self.tab.SetColLabelValue(0, "USER")
        self.tab.SetColLabelValue(1, "Log-In Time")
        self.tab.SetColLabelValue(2, "Status")

        self.tab.SetMinSize((300,300))

        self.text1 = wx.StaticText(self.paneltab, label='Hello', style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)
        self.text2 = wx.StaticText(self.paneltab, label='World', style = wx.ALIGN_CENTER)

        self.SetLayout()
        self.Centre()

    def SetLayout(self):
        sizer = wx.GridBagSizer(5,5)
        sizer.Add((100,-1),     pos=(0,0))
        sizer.Add((100,-1),     pos=(0,1))
        sizer.Add((100,-1),     pos=(0,2))
        sizer.Add(self.text1,   pos=(1,0), span=(1,1), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border=5)
        sizer.Add(self.text2,   pos=(1,2), span=(1,2), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border=5)
        sizer.Add(self.tab,     pos=(2,3), span=(3,5), flag=wx.TOP|wx.EXPAND, border=5)
        self.paneltab.SetSizer(sizer)
        self.paneltab.SetBackgroundColour("#D8BFD8")

def main():
    app = wx.App()
    screen = Screen(None, title='Server Console')
    screen.Show()
    app.MainLoop()
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```